# Python turtle drawing equal cells in a rectangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to use `turtle` in order to draw a rectangle, and then 32 equal cells inside it. But I somehow can't get it right, I don't know why.

Here is the code I've written:

```
import turtle, tkinter, datetime, time

turtle.setx(-400)
turtle.sety(200)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.pencolor('#00807c')
for i in range (0,4):
    x = 800
    if i%2 == 0:
        turtle.fd(x)
    else:
        turtle.fd(x/2)
    turtle.right(90)

def cells(position):
    for i in range (0,4):
        x = 100
        turtle.fd(x)
        turtle.right(90)
        if turtle.pos() == position:
            turtle.fd(x)
            position = turtle.pos()

for j in range(0, 8):
    cells(turtle.pos())
turtle.done()
```

The result is weird, it only draws three or four cells and then the program ends.
I'd be grateful if somebody could possibly help me with this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten your code and I don't understand why you're using a function. I've used 3 loops:

```
loop 3(4):
   loop 2(8):
       loop 1(4):
```

1. The first loop repeats himself 4 times and draws the sides of 1 square
2. The second loop runs the first loop 8 times, so it draws 8 squares next to each other
3. The third loop runs the second loop 4 times, so it draws 4 lines of 8 squares.
   And that makes a field of 32 cells.

My code:

```py
import turtle, tkinter, datetime, time
turtle.penup()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.setx(-400)
turtle.sety(200)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.pencolor('#00807c')
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.pendown()
for i in range (4):
    x = 800
    if i%2 == 0:
        turtle.fd(x)
    else:
        turtle.fd(x/2)
    turtle.right(90)

for w in range (4):
        for i in range (8):
            for i in range (4):
                x = 100
                turtle.fd(x)
                turtle.right(90)
            turtle.forward(x)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(-400,turtle.ycor()-100)
        turtle.pendown()

turtle.done()
```

PS: I've also changed a few things like:

- I hid the turtle
- I changed the speed (to maximum)
- I added a `turtle.penup()`-command before I moved the turtle in the beginning, so you don't see a black line.

Kind regards

spyrolix

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can create two functions, to simplify the logic: One to draw a square, and one to position the turtle at the place to draw a square.  Then, using a little bit of index arithmetic in two nested loops (one for rows, and one for columns), use the indices values, and the side length of a square to draw at the correct location:

Maybe like this:

```
import turtle, tkinter


def draw_square(side):
    """draws a square of side=side starting at the current turtle location
    """
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setheading(0)
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(side)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.penup()
    
def draw_grid(rows, cols):
    """positions the turtle at the correct location, 
    in order to draw a grid of squares
    """
    for jdx in range(rows):
        for idx in range(cols):
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(startx + side*idx, starty + side*jdx)
            draw_square(side)
    

turtle.pencolor('#00807c')
side = 20
startx, starty = 0, 0          # this can be changed, 
                               # other locations used are relative to this starting point
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(startx, starty)

rows, cols = 4, 8              # this can be changed
draw_grid(rows, cols)

turtle.goto(startx, starty)    # return to the starting point

   
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where I would switch from *drawing* to *stamping* to simplify the code and speed it up:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 400

SQUARE = 100

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def cells(t):
    x, y = t.position()

    for dy in range(HEIGHT // SQUARE):
        turtle.goto(x, y + dy * SQUARE)

        for dx in range(WIDTH // SQUARE):
            turtle.stamp()
            turtle.forward(SQUARE)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.shapesize(HEIGHT / CURSOR_SIZE, WIDTH / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.color('#00807c', 'white')
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

turtle.stamp()  # draw outer perimeter

turtle.shapesize(SQUARE / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.goto(SQUARE/2 - WIDTH/2, SQUARE/2 - HEIGHT/2)

cells(turtle)  # draw inner squares

screen.exitonclick()
```

I'd also remove *magic* numbers from the body of the code and declare them at the start to make them easier to adjust.